# npm ERR! peer dep missing: zone.js@^0.7.2 - but zone.js 0.8.4 installed

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

When I get the list of my packages by `npm ls` command I see this alert:

> npm ERR! peer dep missing: zone.js@^0.7.2, required by @angular/core@2.4.10

Here is My `package.json` dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.x",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.3.x",
    "systemjs": "0.20.x",
    "core-js": "2.4.x",
    "rxjs": "5.2.x",
    "zone.js": "0.8.x"
  }
```

Note the last line `"zone.js": "0.8.x"`.
I checked the [semantic-versioning guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning).
Condition `^0.7.2` is ok for My `"zone.js": "0.8.x"` (right now I have 0.8.4 version of zone.js). **Am I right?**

And here is `peerDependencies` section in `MyProjectFolder\node_modules\@angular\core\package.json`:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
}
```

There is no any alerts for `rxjs`, but I have `5.2.0` version in My `package.json`.

Versions of applications in My Windows 10 machine:

```
node -v
v6.9.2

npm -v
4.4.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Caret Ranges**
>
> Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the [major, minor, patch] tuple.

Since the left most non-zero cannot change when using the caret, `^0.7.2` does not match against `0.8.x`. Only versions `>=0.7.2` and `<0.8.0` would be allowed.

You'll need to change your requirement to something in the `0.7.x` range.

Comment: This is it, thanks! Additionally, here the link to more detailed guide about Semver - https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver